# OpenCV.js - detectMultiScale "This Exception cannot be caught"

Tags: javascript, html, opencv

I'm trying to use facial recognition via OpenCV.js, however when I call on the `detectMultiScale()` method of the `CascadeClassifier` object I receive the error:

> Uncaught 6446128 - Exception catching is disabled, this exception cannot be caught. Compile with -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 or DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=2 to catch.

The problem is I'm leveraging a hosted version of `opencv.js` directly from [opencv.org](http://opencv.org) - it's not a build version because I'm unable to build it myself, and therefore cannot follow the error's instructions.

I've followed an example from their GitHub [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/doc/js_tutorials/js_assets/js_face_detection.html) and adapted the code to suit my needs, as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/utils.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img id="test" src="image/with/face.jpg" alt=""/>

    <canvas id="output"></canvas>

    <script>
        let face_cascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
      face_cascade.load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades_cuda/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

        function face_detector() {
                let imgEl = document.getElementById("test");
                let img = cv.imread(imgEl);

                cv.imshow("output", img);
                let src = cv.imread("output");

                let gray = new cv.Mat();
                let msize = new cv.Size(0,0);
                cv.cvtColor(src, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);

                let faces = new cv.RectVector();
                face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, msize, msize); //Error occurs here
            }

        face_detector();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone with experience with OpenCV.js and facial recognition that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [thread](http://answers.opencv.org/question/198918/opencvjs-unable-to-load-haar-cascades/?answer=198936#post-id-198936):

> The xml files are "pre-built" before loading them with the load function. To achieve this it's used the function createFileFromUrl from utils.js. After that we can finally load our classifier from file.

```
let classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier();  // initialize classifier

let utils = new Utils('errorMessage'); //use utils class

let faceCascadeFile = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'; // path to xml

// use createFileFromUrl to "pre-build" the xml
utils.createFileFromUrl(faceCascadeFile, faceCascadeFile, () => {
    classifier.load(faceCascadeFile); // in the callback, load the cascade from file 
});
```

---

## Face Detection Other Example

[TRY IT :](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d99/tutorial_js_face_detection.html)

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let gray = new cv.Mat();
cv.cvtColor(src, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
let faces = new cv.RectVector();
let eyes = new cv.RectVector();
let faceCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
// load pre-trained classifiers
faceCascade.load('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
// detect faces
let msize = new cv.Size(0, 0);

// try to change scaleFactor  and minNeighbors values
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,1.05,0);
for (let i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
    let roiGray = gray.roi(faces.get(i));
    let roiSrc = src.roi(faces.get(i));
    let point1 = new cv.Point(faces.get(i).x, faces.get(i).y);
    let point2 = new cv.Point(faces.get(i).x + faces.get(i).width,
                              faces.get(i).y + faces.get(i).height);
    cv.rectangle(src, point1, point2, [255, 0, 0, 255]);
    roiGray.delete(); roiSrc.delete();
}
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', src);
src.delete(); gray.delete(); faceCascade.delete();
faces.delete(); eyes.delete();
```

Try to change `faceCascade.detectMultiScale` parameters like given examples below:

```
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,1.05,0);
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,1.05,1);

faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,2,0);
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,2,1);

faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,3,0);
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,3,1);

faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,4,0);
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,4,1);
```

Comment: Where does Utils come from? Could you please provide import statement?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
let faceCascadeFile = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'; 
utils.createFileFromUrl(faceCascadeFile, faceCascadeFile, () => {
    console.log('cascade ready to load.');
    let src = cv.imread('imageInit');
    let gray = new cv.Mat();
    cv.cvtColor(src, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
    let faces = new cv.RectVector();
    let faceCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
        faceCascade.load(faceCascadeFile); 
        let msize = new cv.Size(0, 0);
        faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, msize, msize); 
    }); 
}
```

For full code and explanation use this link [Face Detection with Javascript and OpenCV](http://www.recompile.in/2019/11/face-detection-with-javascript-and.html)

or

[Human Eye Detection using Javascript and OpenCV](http://www.recompile.in/2019/11/human-eye-detection-using-javascript.html)