# error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale in Opencv.JS

Tags: javascript, opencv

I have checked and tried these solutions here but none is helping

- [error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale)
- [OpenCV.js - detectMultiScale "This Exception cannot be caught"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162946/opencv-js-detectmultiscale-this-exception-cannot-be-caught)

I also read elsewhere that the problem could be because the file needs to be served via an Http request and so I decided to use ngrok but I still found the same error. Currently am using python http.server

Here is the section of the code:

```
let classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier();

let utils = new Utils('errorMessage'); //use utils class
let faceCascadeFile = "http://localhost:8000/docs/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
//let faceCascadeFile = "D:\Code\Fit-to-Interact-web\docs\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
//let faceCascadeFile = "https://0979da552cb5.ngrok.io/docs/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"; // path to xml

// use createFileFromUrl to "pre-build" the xml
//Make sure to run it in a webserver because it has to do XMLHTTPRequests.
utils.createFileFromUrl(faceCascadeFile, faceCascadeFile, () => {
    classifier.load(faceCascadeFile); // in the callback, load the cascade from file
});
console.log(classifier.empty())
```

Worse when I use the absolute/relative file path I get this error **Not allowed to load local resource** or sometimes the same error:

```
Exception: OpenCV(4.4.0) /build/master-contrib_docs-lin64/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1689: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'
```