what is the correct way to load an xml file into reactjs?
i'm working on a MERN Stack project for the university where users can upload pictures of cars, and i want to use opencv to blur out the license plates, thus i need to use a "haarcascades" file to identify the area.
here is the relevant code:
  const handlePhotosChange = async (e) => {
    const { files } = e.target;
    const selectedPhotos = Array.from(files);

    for (const photo of selectedPhotos) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(photo);

      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        img.onload = () => {
          resolve();
        };
      });

      const mat = cv.imread(img);
      const gray = new cv.Mat();
      cv.cvtColor(mat, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

      const licensePlateCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
      const cascadeLoaded = licensePlateCascade.load(
        "haarcascade_license_plate_rus_16stages.xml"
      );
      console.log("1");
      if (cascadeLoaded) {
        console.log("2");
        const plates = new cv.RectVector();
        const minSize = new cv.Size(30, 30);
        licensePlateCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, plates, 1.1, 3, 0, minSize);

        for (let i = 0; i < plates.size(); i++) {
          const plate = plates.get(i);
          const plateMat = gray.roi(plate);
          cv.GaussianBlur(plateMat, plateMat, new cv.Size(5, 5), 0);
          plateMat.delete();
        }

        const blurredImg = new Image();
        blurredImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([cv.imencode(".jpg", mat)], { type: "image/jpeg" })
        );
        const blurredBlob = await fetch(blurredImg.src).then((res) =>
          res.blob()
        );

        selectedPhotos[selectedPhotos.indexOf(photo)] = blurredBlob;

        plates.delete();
      }

      mat.delete();
      gray.delete();
      licensePlateCascade.delete();
    }

    setPhotos(selectedPhotos);
  };


i'm having a problem with this line specifically :
      const cascadeLoaded = licensePlateCascade.load(
        "haarcascade_license_plate_rus_16stages.xml"
      );

the moment the code executes, i get this error in console:

[ERROR:0@5.090] global persistence.cpp:531 open Can't open file: 'haarcascade_license_plate_rus_16stages.xml' in read mode

i tried putting the full path, using the row github link , putting the file in public, and putting the code and files in the backend.
nothing worked.
the expected behavior: the file loads with no errors.

I see search results dating back to 2018, but also newer ones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162946/opencv-js-detectmultiscale-this-exception-cannot-be-caught

thanks to the comment of @Christoph Rackwitz i was able to find a solution
what you need to do:
1- get the utils.js from OpenCV's GitHub repo.
2- in order for it to work properly, you need to add this line to it (use the relative path of opencv.js you are using)
import * as cv from "../opencv/opencv";

3- import it into the component that you want to used the harrcascade in.
import Utils from "../assets/utils";

also, make sure to import opencv.js too.
4- next, you'll need to put the haarcascade file of your choice in /public.
5- assign it to a variable:
const xmlURL = "haarcascade_xxxx_license_plate.xml";

6- finely, we'll use createFileFromUrl() from utils.js and load our haarcascade file:
utils.createFileFromUrl(xmlURL, xmlURL, () => {
     licensePlateCascade.load(xmlURL);

here is the full function for your convenience:
  const handleLicensePlateDetection = async (e) => {

try {
  console.log("Starting license plate detection...");

  // Clean up previous resources if necessary
  if (window.src) window.src.delete();
  if (window.gray) window.gray.delete();
  if (window.plates) window.plates.delete();
  if (window.licensePlateCascade) window.licensePlateCascade.delete();

  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = async () => {
    console.log("Image loaded successfully.");
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = reader.result;
    image.onload = async () => {
      console.log("Converting image to grayscale...");
      const src = cv.imread(image);
      const gray = new cv.Mat();
      cv.cvtColor(src, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);

      console.log("Loading Haar Cascade XML file...");
      const licensePlateCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
      const xmlURL = "haarcascade_xxx_license_plate.xml"; // Path to the XML file
      utils.createFileFromUrl(xmlURL, xmlURL, () => {
        try {
          licensePlateCascade.load(xmlURL);
          console.log("Haar Cascade XML file loaded successfully.");

          console.log("Detecting license plates...");
          const plates = new cv.RectVector();
          const msize = new cv.Size(0, 0);
          licensePlateCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            plates,
            1.1,
            3,
            0,
            msize,
            msize
          );

          console.log("Applying Gaussian blur to detected plates...");
          for (let i = 0; i < plates.size(); ++i) {
            try {
              const plate = plates.get(i);
              const roi = src.roi(plate);
              cv.GaussianBlur(
                roi,
                roi,
                new cv.Size(23, 23),
                40,
                40,
                cv.BORDER_DEFAULT
              );
              roi.delete();
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(
                "Error applying Gaussian blur to plate:",
                error
              );
            }
          }

          console.log("Displaying the result...");
          cv.imshow("canvas", src);

          // Clean up
          src.delete();
          gray.delete();
          plates.delete();
          licensePlateCascade.delete();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error loading Haar Cascade XML file:", error);
        }
      });
    };
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error initializing license plate detection:", error);
}
  };

note: i'm new to this "AI" stuff and needed the assistance of an AI, thus i don't understand most of what i just pasted

did you try what you just posted, and does it actually work?

@ChristophRackwitz
i only posted it after testing it thoroughly, it works well.
the only problem with it is that i can't choose another photo after, i have to reload the page, or even multiple photos for that matter. But that is beyond the purpose of this thread. I'll figure it out somehow.
if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

good good. just making sure the AI output was actually checked. that's been an issue on the site since ChatGPT became available.
